# Need to change the sequence of values called in a variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have variable which is fetching values from 3 variables, but I want to change the sequence using array maybe. See below my `home.ts` code below to understand

```
  public section1 = `<ol><li>`+this.myname+`</li></ol>`;
  public section2 = `<ol><li>`+this.phno+`</li></ol>`;
  public section3 = `<ol><li>`+this.email+`</li></ol>`;

  public section_sequence = this.section3+this.section2+this.section1;
```

As you can see I have hardcoded `section_sequence`, can I somehow change it to `this.section2+this.section3+this.section1` using array so that I can manage to change this dynamically.

I tried like this, but it did not work.

```
  public section_sequence_array = ["section3", "section2", "section1"];
  public section_sequence = this.section_sequence_array;
```

Comment: what do you want to change dynamically ? the sequence of the sections?

Comment: yes, i wish to change the sequence dynamically from `section_sequence = this.section3+this.section2+this.section1;` to `section_sequence = this.section2+this.section3+this.section1;` or something else

Comment: Somebody replied with the solution but now have deleted that stackblitz

Comment: the answer was on hold its fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Hello check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hb7ap3?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts) that i made.

if i understood you well this will help you, check only the home.html and home.ts

the point is that i put the three sequence in an array and started playing on the indexes of the array.
let me know if you need anything.

**update** well the answer was deleted for a valid reason, i'll include the code here

in your page.html :

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>click any button</ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <button ion-button full color="primary" (click)="changeSequence(1,2,3)">1 - 2 - 3</button>
    <button ion-button full color="secondary" (click)="changeSequence(3,2,1)">3 - 2 - 1</button>
    <button ion-button full color="danger" (click)="changeSequence(1,3,2)">1 - 3 - 2</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
  <div [innerHtml]="section_sequence">

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

this will create buttons to allow the user to change the sequence dynamically.

in your page.ts:

```
section_sequence;
  sections = [
    '<ol><li>a name</li></ol>',
    '<ol><li>a phone</li></ol>',
    '<ol><li>a email</li></ol>'
  ]


  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.section_sequence = this.sections[0]+this.sections[1]+this.sections[2];
  }

  changeSequence(i,y,z){
    this.section_sequence = this.sections[i-1]+this.sections[y-1]+this.sections[z-1];
  }
```

Note that the sections are now in an array so we can link them to an "index" that we are providing to the the function changeSequence(),

we are decreasing the index by 1 since the array starts at 0.

so now you can give `changeSequence()` any sequence you want and it will output the desired order.

Comment: Allow me little time, to check and get back

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18636383)

Comment: @TomAranda you are absolutely right, thank you for letting me know, i updated the answer